# Java трансфер всех файлов из одного хранилища в другое

Tags: java

Объясните, как можно сделать трансфер всех файлов в методе transferAll(Storage storageFrom, Storage storageTo), если есть класс Storage c такими полями

```
long id;
File[] files;
String[] formatsSupported;
String storageCountry;
long storageSize;
```

не могу понять, нужно пройтись по файлам первого хранилища, затем по файлам второго и если файлы второго равны null то как-то заменить их на файлы первого? подскажите я в правильном направлении думаю хоть?

Comment: Мало информации. Если вам нужно сделать метод который будет копировать всю папку в другую папку, то следует посмотреть в сторону https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Comment: это java core тема исключений тут мне можно по массивам проходится и условия ставить, больше ничего